# python : after def a combobox, the result show none

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a program with a combobox, while I define the combobox, the result shown is `None`, but if I don't define the combobox, the results are what I want.

As my program needs to def a combobox, how can I solve the problem with the result showing `None`?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("search store")

ttk.Label(win, text="select a area:").grid(column=0, row=0) 

def search():
    action.configure( text = "SEARCH" )
    print(e())

def e():  
    cmb = tk.StringVar()      
    cmb1 = ttk.Combobox(win, width=30, textvariable=cmb,state='readonly')
    cmb1['values'] = ('place 1', 'place 2', 'place 3', 'place 4' ) 
    cmb1.grid(column=0, row=2)
    cmb1.current(0)

action = ttk.Button(win, text="SEARCH", command=search)
action.grid(column=2, row=1)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: In search command callback, you're adding a combox. Looks, like your intent is to create a combobox with a search button. 

For this, you need to setup GUI components first. 

Using OOP paradigm is better here for sanity because you'll need to pass references to components in command callback if you'll like to access their values using a functional style. https://gist.github.com/osule/9a8b540c82b183baf7950b82ef5b8d5c

Comment: https://dpaste.de/eaYs   i try your method to do , in my main program, i have 4 combobox. the user first will choose 1 combobox first, the 1st combobox do have 3 option "a","b","c". If the user choose "a", then 2nd combobox will appear,  If the user choose "b", then 3rd combobox will appear,  If the user choose "c", then 4th combobox will appear, this is what i what to write, but the program cant run on the 3rd and 4th combobox. When i choose "c", and choose a option in 4th combobox, the result only print the 1st combobox but "none" or "error" in both 3rd and 4th combobox..@Baduker

Answer (score 0):

The search button command callback needs to be passed a reference to the combobox.

The current workaround to access this reference by setting up the combobox in the search button command callback isn't the right way to go about this.

Setup the combobox. Then when setting up the Button, pass the reference to combobox to the Button command callback *e.g.*

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar
from tkinter.ttk import Label, Combobox, Button

win = Tk()

def search(cmb1):
    print(cmb1.get())


def setup_combo_box():
    cmb1 = Combobox(win, width=30, textvariable=StringVar(), state='readonly')
    cmb1['values'] = ('place 1', 'place 2', 'place 3', 'place 4' ) 
    cmb1.grid(column=0, row=2)
    cmb1.current(0)
    return cmb1

cmb1 = setup_combo_box()
action = Button(win, text="SEARCH", command=lambda: search(cmb1))
action.grid(column=2, row=1)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: [link](https://dpaste.de/HL1H) there is the one i use your method to do in my main program, but as the program has 3 combobox and dictiontary , the result print out still have "None" . How to fix it ? Thanks. @Oluwafemi Sule

Comment: i just do this , but the result is none on the second result. @Oluwafemi Sule